# How to echo something in a while loop with sleep()?

Tags: php, csv, while-loop, sleep, fopen

I've got a while loop to read a csv file with customer data (Name, Email, Website). i use to echo each row each second. so i do a while loop with sleep(1) and alot of hope, but the browser is waitong untill its fully loeaded. i know, thats how php works and maybe its easy with javacript, but i've got really no glue about javascript. Even flush() technics dont works. Maybe a problem on my host? i use one.com

i tried already just the sleep() within the loop. - loading untill finished
i tried already flush functions -  same same

```
$handle = fopen ("csv.csv","r");
$csv = array();

while ( ($data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, "\t")) !== FALSE ) {
    $csv[] = $data;
    echo "Name=".$data[0]."<br>Email=".$data[1]."<br>Website=".$data[2];
    sleep(1);
}
fclose ($handle);
```

Comment: If I were you, I would put my time and effort into learn Javascript (and Ajax). Using `sleep()` on a web page is not recommended since it won't scale well since those calls will be blocking. It's better to fetch all the data from the back end in one go and present it how you want it using Javascript.

Comment: It's just and only to use for me and my coworker. the real reason why we needs that is a bit more complicated, but in this way its the functionality. csv with hundrets of rows, each row has 3 cols and i need to wait 1 sec to output it in a webbrowser. 
If you have a javascript solution for that, please provide me.

Comment: Sorry. I don't have a finished script for it, nor is SO the correct place to ask for it. We're glad to help you sort out issues with your existing code, but we're not here to do it for you.

Comment: I know. and i just need a hint how to do it. Otherwise we can answer EVERY question in stackoverflow with "Learn how to do it" :/
I know its possible to flush anything within a while loop. it just not workung on my webserver. Maybe i can put all contents of the csv in an array and let javascript show it each one after 1 sec delay. in that way i could need the javascript part (loop with echo and delay) or a better solution to get an echo in a while loop

Comment: Google something like "Get started with Ajax" to begin with and take it one step at the time. JS also have functions to "delay" actions using either `setTimeout()` for a one-off, or `setInterval()` for execute some code every nth millisecond.

Comment: i finaly put all in one array... i put it into javascript in an loop like @Rahul explained. i was not counting, so i put a new variable ´a´ to count. that works. but i dont get my contents from my array. its allways undefined

Comment: Post a new question with that code and we should be able to help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both, php and javascript to perform this operation.

Step 1: Javascript will do a single ajax call on php to get the csv data into form of json.

Step 2: PHP will read the csv file, store data into an array and return the json encoded data back to javascript.

Step 3: Loop through the backend data in javascript using setInterval function like this:

```
var data = /* json data from ajax call */;

var i=0, html='';
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // Perform the operation here, which will print some data at interval of 1 second
    if(i==data.length) {
        clearInterval(loop);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i used to searching long time to get it done finaly, to get my array into javascript. So the solution is finaly `var data = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $data).'"' ?>];` and it works fine =)